# Using System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger in code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, expression-blend

I am trying to use the `System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger` in code (as opposed to in XAML). I have this code.

Main code:

```
var textBox = new TextBox();
var triggerAction = new TextBoxTrigger();
var eventTrigger = new EventTrigger("TextChanged");
eventTrigger.Actions.Add(triggerAction);
Interaction.GetTriggers(textBox).Add(eventTrigger);

// This triggers the event
textBox.Text = "Changed";
```

TextBoxTrigger.cs:

```
public class TextBoxTrigger : TriggerAction<TextBox>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {                        
    }
}
```

My breakpoint on Invoke method in `TextBoxTrigger` never gets hit. An interesting thing is that I have tried this with my custom objects (rather than TextBox), derived from `DependencyObject` and `UIElement`, both of these worked. Whenever I change the base class to `FrameworkElement` (or any other derived class), the action stops being invoked and furthermore, the event is `null`.

What am I missing?  It's been giving me a headache all day long, please help.